# SSL and Https in mvc asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, https

Would you please help me.
I'm a bit confused on how to use the attribute  `[RequiresHttps]` and the `<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />`. My question is:

If I use `<authentication mode="Forms"> <forms requireSSL="true">` and `<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />` then I don't need to use the attribute `[RequiresHttps]`?

In my opinion, `<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />` instructs the application  to manage the auth cookie with https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a secure website you need to use

1. `RequiresHttps`  which force the request to be served only for https and I recommend setting this attribute as global filter
2. Set the attribute `<httpCookies requireSSL="true" httpOnlyCookies="true" />` where `httpOnlyCookies` disable the capability of accessing the cookies from client side scripts and requireSSL forces all cookies to be passed only through secured http requests

For more details about the securing cookies please refer to [this](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/03/c-is-for-cookie-h-is-for-hacker.html) article by Troy Hunt

Comment: Thank you.
two more questions...
1. so, I always have to use the attribute RequireHttps and <httpCookies requireSSL="true" /> wherever my app manage to receive important info, it's not one or another for a better security in specific scenarios is good to use both?

2. where am I supposed to check your answer as correct in order to notice to other persons that your answer fulfill my expectations?

Comment: Hello, first you should use both https and secure cookies in all scenarios not just for important info such as login and you can check the following link for more details http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/05/your-login-form-posts-to-https-but-you.html, second you should mark it if you feel that it is well written and works for you also check this for details http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work